# How to post to Instagram from my 3rd party app?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm building a JEE app that schedules the user's posts in their social media. After long hours of researches, some resources say that instagram does not allow 3rd party apps to post via their API, while others say it has become possible. 
So can I post via those API? and if not, how can I get their permission to post? (apparently there's no way to contact them directly) 
Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you are posting on behalf of IG-user with Business Account. Did you check out official tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing?

Comment: Yes I did ckeck them, but it's written that The Content Publishing API are only accessible by Instagram or Facebook partners, does that mean that I have to apply for a partenrship with IG?